# Resetting form and variables without page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I've got a page with multiple file links. On clicking any link, a contact form opens in the modal. On successful submit, the file url is made available with the success message.

Since i don't want to to make individual forms for every link, i've placed the files in a folder and all the link "names" match the filenames exactly. 
The subject for the form and the file link name are assigned through javascript to php.

I'd like to reset all the values on the form when i click a different file download link. I've read that sessions is one way to do this, but i don't know enough php to execute this correctly.

I'd appreciate some pointers

Here are my files

https://www.dropbox.com/s/jcw88r6np5faw5r/tester.php?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/a2fw38n1vxkb05n/contact_m1.php?dl=0

### Tester.php - the button and form elements

```
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="text-xs-center"><a class="btn btn-danger" name="fire_prevention_system"  onclick="calculate()" href="#myModal" id="modellink" data-toggle="modal"> DOWNLOAD  </a> <div class="modal-container"></div></div>
            <div class="text-xs-center"><a class="btn btn-danger" name="FDSS"  onclick="calculate()" href="#myModal" id="modellink" data-toggle="modal"> DOWNLOAD  </a> <div class="modal-container"></div></div>
            <div class="text-xs-center"><a class="btn btn-danger" name="Aerosol_Fire_Suppression_Catalogue"  onclick="calculate()" href="#myModal" id="modellink" data-toggle="modal"> DOWNLOAD </a> <div class="modal-container"></div></div>
            <div class="text-xs-center"><a class="btn btn-danger" name="Aerosol_system"  onclick="calculate()" href="#myModal" id="modellink" data-toggle="modal"> DOWNLOAD </a> <div class="modal-container"></div></div>
            <div class="text-xs-center"><a class="btn btn-danger" name="company_introduction_2017"  onclick="calculate()" href="#myModal" id="modellink" data-toggle="modal"> DOWNLOAD </a> <div class="modal-container"></div></div>
            <div class="text-xs-center"><a class="btn btn-danger" name="Twin-Trolley_Trailers_Acc"  onclick="calculate()" href="#myModal" id="modellink" data-toggle="modal"> DOWNLOAD </a> <div class="modal-container"></div></div>
            <div class="text-xs-center"><a class="btn btn-danger" name="how-to-operate-"  onclick="calculate()" href="#myModal" id="modellink" data-toggle="modal"> DOWNLOAD </a> <div class="modal-container"></div></div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript"> 
        function calculate() {
        var x = document.getElementById("modellink").name;
        document.getElementById("subject").value = x;
        }
        </script>

        <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="false">&times;</button>
                        <h6 class="modal-title">File Download Request</h6>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-style" id="contact_form">
            <div id="contact_results"></div>
            <form id="contact_body" method="post" action="contact_m1.php">
            <input type="text" style="display:none;" id="subject" name="subject" value="">
                <label for="name"><span>Name <span class="required">*</span></span>
                    <input type="text" name="name" data-required="true"/>
                </label>
                <label for="email"><span>Email <span class="required">*</span></span>
                    <input type="email" name="email" data-required="true"/>
                </label>
                <label><span>Mobile <span class="required">*</span></span>
                    <input type="text" name="phone1" maxlength="4" placeholder="+91" data-required="true"/>&mdash;
                    <input type="text" name="phone2" maxlength="15" data-required="true"/>
                </label>
                <label for="company"><span>Organisation <span class="required">*</span></span>
                    <input type="text" name="company" data-required="true"/>
                </label>       
                <label for="message"><span>Message <span class="required">*</span></span>
                    <textarea name="message" data-required="true"></textarea>
                </label>
                <label><span>&nbsp;</span>
                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                </label>
            </form>
        </div>
        </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <script type="text/javascript">
        var border_color = "#C2C2C2"; //initial input border color

        $("#contact_body").submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault(); //prevent default action 
            proceed = true;

//simple input validation
$($(this).find("input[data-required=true], textarea[data-required=true]")).each(function(){
        if(!$.trim($(this).val())){ //if this field is empty 
            $(this).css('border-color','red'); //change border color to red   
            proceed = false; //set do not proceed flag
        }
        //check invalid email
        var email_reg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/; 
        if($(this).attr("type")=="email" && !email_reg.test($.trim($(this).val()))){
            $(this).css('border-color','red'); //change border color to red   
            proceed = false; //set do not proceed flag              
        }   
}).on("input", function(){ //change border color to original
     $(this).css('border-color', border_color);
});

//if everything's ok, continue with Ajax form submit
if(proceed){ 
    var post_url = $(this).attr("action"); //get form action url
    var request_method = $(this).attr("method"); //get form GET/POST method
    var form_data = new FormData(this); //Creates new FormData object
    var x = void 0;

    $.ajax({ //ajax form submit
        url : post_url,
        type: request_method,
        data : form_data,
        dataType : "json",
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false
    }).done(function(res){ //fetch server "json" messages when done
        if(res.type == "error"){
            $("#contact_results").html('<div class="error">'+ res.text +"</div>");
        }

        if(res.type == "done"){
            $("#contact_results").html('<div class="success">'+ res.text + res.text2 +"</div>");
            $("#contact_form #contact_body").slideUp(); //hide form after success
        }
    });
}
        });
        </script>
```

### CONTACT_M1.php

```
after assigning recepient email ...
if($_POST){

    $sender_name    = filter_var($_POST["name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //capture sender name
    $sender_email   = filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //capture sender email
    $country_code   = filter_var($_POST["phone1"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $phone_number   = filter_var($_POST["phone2"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $company        = filter_var($_POST["company"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $subject        = filter_var($_POST["subject"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $message        = filter_var($_POST["message"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //capture message     
    $link           = $_POST["subject"]; //value carried over from tester.php

...
      $headers = "From:".$from_email."\r\n".
       "Reply-To: ".$sender_email. "\n" .
        "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
        $body = $emailText;
   }

    $sentMail = mail($recipient_email, $subject, $body, $headers);
    if($sentMail) //output success or failure messages
    {       
        print json_encode(array('type'=>'done', 'text' => 'Thank you for your email', text2 => '<a href=\testsite/manuals/'.$link.'.pdf \ target=\_blank \><br> FILE DOWNLOAD LINK: '.$link.'</a>'));
    exit;
    }else{
        print json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration.'));  
    exit;
    }
```

Comment: I think this is might be what you're looking for: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset - when someone has clicked a download, reset the form ready to populate with your new values.

Comment: Add a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/) in your question and not only some links to external resources.

Comment: Thank you Joe, I will look up your suggestion

Comment: Andreas, the links are to my own files. they seemed to be too long to post in the comments. However, have edited my question with relevant code